# Is event definition in model file (.cto) necessary when using composer-rest-server ?

Tags: events, hyperledger-composer

If I want to develop a node.js application for a Hyperledger Fabric Composer business network, it is necessary to define (in the model file) events that are emitted, whenever a transaction takes place. Otherwise, the node.js application is not "informed" about those transactions (see https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/business-network/publishing-events.html).

Defining the events (in the model file ... and emitting them in the respective transaction processor functions) makes it possible for the node.js application to subscribe to those events (and therefore to be informed about transactions happening.)

So far I understand it.

My question is the following:

When I use the composer rest server (i.e. the automatically generated node.js application) instead of developing my "own" node.js application, do I still have to define the events for the transactions defined in the model file (.cto)? 
Or is this not necessary because the composer rest server does not use those events anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would still need to define events in your model, then publish them in your transaction code (and subsequently consume them (subscribe) them from a client - whether composer-client or websockets etc.  So regardless of whether you're using the REST APIs, Composer client APIs or even the CLI.

So if you POST a transaction from your REST client (eg. browser)- which sends it to the REST server - you must have defined an event (in your model) AND  furthermore, your transaction logic would have to emit that event - for any listener to process it.

Comment: Pardon me, I'm new to this. But I still don't get the necessity of emitting and subscribing to the events. Wouldn't using `@returns` be convenient instead?

Comment: np. Events are used to say 'a business event has taken place, notify the application that's listening for events' - eg Websockets server. Returns is convenient sure, its for returning data (results) sets but not event-driven.